# Limit the number of documents that user can create

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection named `triggers` I want to limit the number of documents *per* user on this collection, let's say 5.

I can create a counter with a Firebase function and set it as read-only, but I do not know how to limit it to the rules.

With Firestore Rules, is it possible to limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can create a counter with a Firebase function and set it as read-only, but I do not know how to limit it to the rules.

You can read the document where you are storing the count as shown below (e.g. in users collection):

```
match /triggers/{triggerId} {
  allow create: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.count < 5;
}
```

As Cloud Functions run asynchronously, this rule might fail if the user attempts to add multiple documents at once (i.e. document is added before the count is updated). You can alternatively add documents through a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) as well and perform all validations there.

Comment: If the OP needs exactly 5, then it should be `<= 5`.

Comment: I assumed OP is storing the exact count in the document so `<=` will allow to add document even if count in doc is 5.